# Can you use a negative tag question after a sentence with 2 words that make it negative?

Tags: negation, question-tags

We always use kind of the opposite meaning of the main sentence in tag question. For example:

> He hasn't eaten yet, has he?

But what should we do when there's another word that makes a sentence negative in it? For example, which of these 2 is correct?

1. He hasn't got any children, has he?
2. He hasn't got any children, hasn't he?

Comment: I don't see the difference between "he hasn't eaten" and "he hasn't got any."  Why do you think they're different?

Comment: Our teacher said when there is another word with negative meaning in the main sentence (plus a negative verb), tag question has to be negative. Just like when you multiple 2 negative numbers and the answer is a positive one. Although I really don't think what he said was correct.

Comment: Idiomatically, it's *I've got money, **haven't I**?*, with the standard "negated verb" version being *I **haven't** got money, **have I**?* and the "negated noun" version being *I've got **no** money, **have I**?* Perhaps your teacher is thinking of the "non-standard, colloquial" double negation in forms like *I **haven't / ain't** got **no** money, **have I**?*, where that extraneous negating ***no*** doesn't affect either the meaning OR the choice of tag question form.

Comment: What is the extra negative word in the statement? _Any_? If so, there's some confusion here. _Any_ is not a negative trigger like _not_ or _never_ or _deny_; rather, it's a [Negative Polarity Item](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+negative+polarity+item) like _ever_ or _at all_ or _budge_, which can only occur grammatically in a negative context. The _hasn't_ is negative, and the _any_ is an NPI licensed by _hasn't_. NPIs don't count in assessing tag questions, so (1) above is correct, while (2) is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 0):

"Has he" is correct. "Any" doesn't *make* a sentence negative. Instead, it's a word that, in this sense, can only be used in a context that is *already* negative.